# How to block docker-mapped ports with a firewall from outside the host without messing up docker routing inside the host?

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, docker, firewalld

I have a docker container running on a host with some port mapped to a port on the host.

`docker run -d -p 9009:9009  someserver`

I want this machine firewalled off from the internet except for 80, 443 and 22.

But I still want processes inside the host to be able to connect to 9009.

I was a little shocked to find out docker seems to completely circumvent any firewall rules for dropping packets.

I tried on centos 7 with both **firewalld** and **iptables** to block everything except 80, 443, and 22.   Somehow I was still able to get at the docker port-mapped container (port 9009) from outside the host!  Some solutions I found seem to mess up routing entirely for docker - either make docker containers not be able to get to the internet or whatever.

Is my scenario possible?

This seems to be asking the same question:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66136/docker-port-forwarding-exposure

Comment: Could you provide a `netstat -an` and `iptables -L` from the host while the docker is running?

Answer (score 9):

It looks like I can bind my exposed container ports to localhost only.

`docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:9009:9009  someserver`